# Jackson custom deserializer for a field while using default deserializer for the rest of the fields?

Tags: java, jackson

I need to deserialize a JSON that has a field into another field.

For example, here is the JSON where I want the property `oldField` to be deserialized into the field `newField` in the `DataModel`.

```json
{
   // Some other fields are not shown
   "oldField": {
       "foo": "Some value"
   }
}
```

```java
class DataModel {
  // Some other fields are not shown
  NewField newField;
}

class NewField {
  String foo;
}
```

The reason is because the JSON was deserialized from an old data model that has been changed, i.e. `oldField` being renamed to `newField` in the `DataModel` class. I can write a custom deserializer for `DataModel` class but it means I have to manually deserialize all other fields in addition to the `newField`.

Is there a way that I can only provide the custom deserialize for the field I am interested in while leaving other things to the default deserializer provided by Jackson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it with `@JsonAlias`

```
class DataModel {
  // Some other fields are not shown
  @JsonAlias("oldField")
  NewField newField;
}

class NewField {
  String foo;
}
```

Comment: I am not aware of this. Is it possible to provide custom deserializer in addition with the `JsonAlias`? I also need to do a bit of conversion from the old field names to the new field names.

Comment: Sure, you can add `@JsonDeserialize(using = NewFieldDeserializer.class)`, NewFieldDeserializer should extend `StdDeserializer<NewField>` and in deserialize implementation add any of your conversions

Comment: but, since JsonDeserialize will take precedence over JsonAlias, there is little sense to use both.

Comment: Your solution works for me. I will mark this as `answered`.